# WPF: Accessing grid defined under Data Template which inturn is defined under Resource dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Inputs: I have a theme xaml file where in all the data templates are defined for specific datatypes. Refer below, I have a data template of type Table consisting of grid. The data template is defined under resource dictionary. I have kept Grid empty and just given name as DynamicGrid. The grid content willbe decided by me at run time and so I have kept it empty. ( example the grid can be 2 by 2 table with each cell as textbox and some textbox can span till any row or any column).

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:th="clr-namespace:ThemeDataModel"
xmlns:my="clr-namespace:ThemeEditor"
xmlns:utility="clr-namespace:Utility.Wpf;assembly=Utility"
xmlns:wa="clr-namespace:WorkAreaControl;assembly=WorkAreaControl"
xmlns:p="clr-namespace:ThemeEditor.Properties"
>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="temData" DataType="{x:Type th:Table}">
        <Grid x:Name="DynamicGrid">

        </Grid>
   </DataTemplate> 
 ...
```

Question: My quesion is how do i access the grid ( name as DynamicGrid ) from the C# code behind. So my workflow is, whenever an object of type "Table" is added in my themearea then it should use the above datatemplate and I should be able to access the grid under the data template and fill it dynamically. I am new to WPF so kindly suggest. If I hardcode and define the grid content in xaml file itself I am able to get the table but I want to do it dynamically.

Then how can I accomplish this ? When my object of type Table is added i need that grid to be display inside a dragresize control which is already there. for example. refer below wokring example. When object of type "AnotherTable" is added it adds a grid with tooltip and a textblock with white backgroud in it.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type th:AnotherTable}">
    <Grid ToolTip="{DynamicResource AreaTip}">
        <TextBlock Text="{DynamicResource Text}" Background="White"></TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

My requirement is I dont know how the grid will look like and it has to be decided at run time.

Comment: Why are you using a data template?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx. Whatever you're trying to do, procedural code is not the answer in WPF.

Comment: Also read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: If you 'really' have to do this then you will need to look at the visual tree and then locate your grid. This is a pretty good example of how you could accomplish this http://blog.falafel.com/finding-controls-by-type-in-silverlight-and-wpf/